# Passing a deserialized json string between methods

Tags: apexrest

I have a class that is performing a callout and getting a response that has multiple entities to work with. At the moment when I get the response I'm converting the response into a Json string and then passing that string to a number of different methods to process the detail. The first thing each method needs to do is to deserialize the jsonString into a Typed classes that i have created:

```
JobResponse jresp =  (JobResponse)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, JobResponse.class);
```

What i am wondering is can I deserialize this once and then pass my jresp between the methods that need to process the response?

```
    public class example{
    public class JobResponse{
        public string example{get; set;}
    }
    @future(callout=true)
    public static void callout(){
            //make a callout and get a response

            JobResponse jresp =  (JobResponse)JSON.deserialize(jsonString, JobResponse.class);
    }

    public static ProcessMethod(???){
        //process jresp
    }

}
```

If this is possible, what constructor would i use in the ProcessMethod to pass in the Job Response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can easily do this. Also it would be better because it will save your CPU processing time. In your method you need to pass the class instance  and then your method you can easily use that.

```
public static ProcessMethod(JobResponse jresp){
        //process jresp
}
```